# Hudson svn credentials

Tags: hudson

How to enter subversion credentials in Hudson by shell? 
I've tried to generate file hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.xml in HUDSON_HOME and reload configuration, but changes weren't applied.

Comment: Restart Hudson. It worked for me when I hosed my hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.xml file. The safest way is to stop Hudson. Replace/change the file and start Hudson again. Remember that the password always needs to be encrypted. If you just want to change it remotely, use the URL for adding credentials http://Server:Port/scm/SubversionSCM/enterCredential You should also be able to sent a post request back to Hudson that contains the credentials you need. Hudson will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to enter a credential from the shell is to use "svn" executable. Hudson recognizes the `~/.subversion/auth` directory that it creates.

Comment: However, you'd need to do that for each node that the job would run on (slaves).

Comment: Right. Using that from Jenkins UI would avoid that need, but then the question was how to enter credentials from shell. Hmm, maybe this could be a new Jenkins CLI command?

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows the global credenentials are stored under `%APPDATA%\Subversion\auth`. The following Groovy code helps generating these credentials:

```
SVNRepository repository = SVNRepositoryFactory.create(SVNURL.parseURIEncoded(url))
ISVNAuthenticationManager authManager = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager(SVNWCUtil.defaultConfigurationDirectory,"AD\user","password",true)
repository.setAuthenticationManager(authManager)
repository.getDir("", -1, null ,(Collection)null) // or some random SVN operation
```

Libraries used in the code above (example in Gradle):

```
compile 'org.tmatesoft.svnkit:org.tmatesoft.svnkit:1.7.8'
compile 'net.java.dev.jna:jna:3.4.0' // so wincrypt is available
```

Make sure you run the code with the same user Hudson runs on the Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

Just start with the Hudson.
Install all required Plug-Ins.
Hit the link,EX:-localhost:8080/hudson
Click on the add job/Create job.
While choosing the options SVN will be present there,Give the SVN location.
Credentials link is present out there.Click on that link.
A form will get open,provide valid credentials for that location of SVN.
Observe the Success message on the screen and then get back to the Create job,Complete with Job creation and Build the task.