# Authenticate subversion remotely

Tags: java, svn, authentication, jenkins

I'm developing an application based on java which allows one to manage jenkins jobs remotely.

How can I insert svn user and password when creating a new job?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any method of doing so, however you can have the master cache credentials after authenticating successfully once.

This can be found under: Manage Jenkins>Configure System>Subversion. Just check the box which specifies "Update default Subversion credentials cache after successful authentication".

If you have multiple repositories this won't help, but if your jobs use the same repo then you should be able to create a new job via the api without explicitly specifying the SVN credentials.

Comment: yes it works only when svn credentials had been inserted before but if I want to put specify new repository I think I must put them manually from Jenkins

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541060/hudson-svn-credentials) thread might help you.