# Hudson global SVN credential storing?

Tags: svn, hudson

Maybe I am using hudson wrong, but I have a user for svn that has access to all the projects in the repo.  I have built a job that is trying to pass a parameter in the svn location (https://svn.company.com/project/branches/$BRANCH_NAME) from a drop down list.  The catch is that Hudson seems to want credentials for each repo.  The "global override" for credentials is a little sketchy and I am not exactly sure, but it doesn't seem to work the way I think it should.

Is there a way to define a true global user for a project?  More specifically, if I have a user in svn 'hudson' that has checkout access to everything, can I configure hudson to always use hudson's svn credentials no matter what job I add in the Hudson job server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apparently Hudson understands (via SVNKit) [credentials in `~/.subversion/auth`][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4652362/60462

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a global user to the subversion repo that had access to all the projects, instead of limiting the access per project.  Still have to add the credentials per job each time, since the "Global" svn setting in Hudson is misrepresented.

Answer (score 0):

What user is running your Hudson instance?

What you need to do is log in as that user (into the Hudson root directory) and do a few `svn ls --username ...` operations to set the user name and password for those repositories. This user you mention in `--username` does not have to be the same as the Hudson user. What that will do is create a `$HOME/.subversion/auth` record for that repository for the user running Hudson. That will become the universal checkout record that Hudson will attempt to use for the project (unless the project has its own Subversion credentials).